# C language variable type float and integer pass in mysql

Tags: mysql, c

I'm a beginner in C and mysql programing.For some days now I am trying to write float and integer values that i get from sensors to a database in mySQL.So far i'm just getting an error "too many arguments to function ‘mysql_query’" and " expected ‘const char *’".Below is my simple code.

```
int main()
{
    int var1 = 1;
    float var2 = 5.1;
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, host, user, pass, dbname,port, unix_socket, flag))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError: %s [%d]\n",mysql_error(conn),mysql_errno(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connection successful!\n"); 
    mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO variables (var1) VALUE  ('%d');",var1);   
    mysql_query(conn, mysql_query );
}
```

Comment: You really should read up on how the functions work before making wild expectations of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice idea, but `mysql_query` doesn't work with variable arguments.

You need to store the query in a buffer:

```
char buff[1024];

snprintf(buff, sizeof buff, "INSERT INTO variables (var1) VALUES  ('%d');",var1);
```

and then you can call `mysql_query` with this buffer:

```
mysql_query(conn, buff);
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by @PaulOgilvie: Notice `VALUES` instead of `VALUE` in the query.

Comment: I also believe that VALUE should be VALUES.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a prepared statement, which would also take care of the types and all that (*assuming `conn` is a valid connection object*)

```
MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
MYSQL_BIND params[1];
const char *query;

// This is necessary or the program will crash
memset(params, 0, sizeof(params));

query = "INSERT INTO variables (var1) VALUES (?)";
stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);

params[0].buffer = &var1;
params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
if (stmt == NULL)
    exit(1); // Ideally handle the error and solve the problem
             // but for simplicity ...
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, query, strlen(query)) != 0)
    exit(1);
if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, params) != 0)
    exit(1);
if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt) != 0) {
     // Ideally print mysql's error
    fprintf(stderr, "an error occurred\n");
}
mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
```

This is the good safe way to do this, and also you can reuse the prepared statement as many times as you want and they promise it will be faster and more efficient because the query is **prepared** so the execution plan is known and you don't need to use the `snprintf()` which by the way should be checked for errors and also, you should check if the query did fit into the target array, read the documentation for that.

Also, you don't need to worry about escaping strings or anything. It will all be handled transparently for you. As long as you use the correct type and of course, specify the length of strings.

Note that you can bind parameters and results too in *SELECT* queries.

Comment: Program works like a charm, but i do not understand how do i pass more than one var integer, and also i need to pass some float values. I have tried usingquery = "INSERT INTO variables (var1,var2) VALUES (?,?)"; but with no luck.
stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);

params[0].buffer = &var1;
params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;params[1].buffer = &var2;
params1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;

Comment: @AnžeLukežič It's not hard. Just add more `params` with types `MYSQL_TYPE_LONG` and `MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT` I think. You should be very careful not to pass the wrong type because undefined behavior will occur. And also, remember to increase the size of the `params` array according to your needs (*how many parameters total*).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't need "VALUES" here instead of "VALUE":

```
mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO variables (var1) VALUE  ('%d');",var1);
```

Comment: Yes, it should be `VALUES` instead of `VALUE`, but `mysql_query` doesn't accept variable arguments.

Comment: Yeah, guess there are lots of problems. Just mentioned the first show-stopper I saw.